# how to register an instance of object with ASP.NET MVC and MEF?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mef

We are building an ASP.NET MVC 4 application and taking advantage of MEF Lightweight Composition. It works great for everything we have so far.

But we **would like to create a couple of parts manually at start-up and add them to the container**. This is quite trivial in full MEF, but for some reason, I can't seem to find the right way to do this.

Comment: What are you doing and what is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: Well, currently, nothing. We use [Shared] parts and the first time it is hit, it initialize itself. The down side of this is that it is all declared async because it makes calls to other resources and it is not clean. I am sure I can get my hands on the container somehow. Just checking for the recommended approach.

Comment: Have you considered some sort of DI (perhaps Unity)? MEF is more for discovery (like plugins) where DI is more for having things created and injected as you configure (or tell it) which sounds more like what you are doing.